# What is mars.sslproviders.net in Azure Portal

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I am currently wondering what mars.sslproviders.net as per image attached is? The url has been hit twice from my client.

[image]

Comment: If your client is calling that URL, have you considered that a NuGet package (or other library) you have used might be accessing it? I'm not sure how else we can guess what it is.

Comment: All I can tell is that it's registered through a registrar called "NameSilo" and it uses AWS' Route53 nameservers.